# Alignment issues in iMessage app

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, imessage-extension

I've been facing weird alignment issues while trying to create an iMessage app.

Please find the screenshots below.

- After loading the app, all the elements are against the borders...

[image]

- Going to expanded mode, makes them align correctly.

[image]

- Returning to compact mode keeps the alignment as expected.

[image]

The problem happens only on the first load. Apart from the constraints in IB, I've never modified their placement or anything else.

Comment: I'm facing same issue with iMessage. Any luck with sorting it out?

Comment: @VadimTikanov , no luck. :( Let me know if you figure a way out.

Comment: Same issue :( ... anybody any luck?

Comment: I guess it happens only while running from XCode.

Comment: Enclosing all of these in a `UIStackView`, keeps it clean. At least, that's what I did. @NikhilManapure, nope, it happens whenever.

Comment: @Shyam That is a weird behavior of iOS and really thanks for the `UIStackView` thing, I will surely test that.